# CRFClassifier java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: maxAdditionalKnownLCWords

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to use the CRFClassifier of the Stanford NLP library.

The trained model is supposed to be in a .ser file, but when I pass the deserialized object to the CRFClassifier constructor I get the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: maxAdditionalKnownLCWords
```

This is what I tried, I've also tried to use the property file that was given in the same directory. I get the same error regardless of whether I pass the prop file or not though:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.*;
import java.util.*;

public class StanfordParserTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String propfile = "/Users/--------/Documents/Programming/Java/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.prop";
        FileReader p_file_reader = null;
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try{
            p_file_reader = new FileReader(propfile);
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (p_file_reader != null){
            try{
                prop.load(p_file_reader);
                p_file_reader.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        ObjectInputStream o_in = null;
        String serializedClassifier = "/Users/--------/Documents/Programming/Java/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser";
        try{
            FileInputStream f_in = new FileInputStream(serializedClassifier);
            o_in = new ObjectInputStream(f_in);
            f_in.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(o_in);
        System.out.println(prop);
        AbstractSequenceClassifier<CoreLabel> classifier = null;
        try{    
            classifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifier(o_in, prop);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(classifier);

    }

}
```

This is the output:

```
java.io.ObjectInputStream@6ff3c5b5
{useDisjunctive=true, useSequences=true, serializeTo=english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz, useOccurrencePatterns=true, unknownWordDistSimClass=0, useClassFeature=true, testFile=/u/nlp/data/ner/column_data/all.3class.test, useQN=true, useTypeSeqs=true, usePrevSequences=true, featureDiffThresh=0.05, wordFunction=edu.stanford.nlp.process.AmericanizeFunction, distSimLexicon=/u/nlp/data/pos_tags_are_useless/egw4-reut.512.clusters, wordShape=chris2useLC, usePrev=true, maxLeft=1, useNextRealWord=true, useTypeSeqs2=true, map=word=0,answer=1, disjunctionWidth=5, useWord=true, QNsize=25, useLastRealWord=true, numberEquivalenceDistSim=true, useDistSim=true, useNGrams=true, saveFeatureIndexToDisk=true, useLongSequences=true, useObservedSequencesOnly=true, readerAndWriter=edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ColumnDocumentReaderAndWriter, maxNGramLeng=6, normalize=true, trainFileList=/u/nlp/data/ner/column_data/ace23.3class.train,/u/nlp/data/ner/column_data/muc6.3class.ptb.train,/u/nlp/data/ner/column_data/muc7.3class.ptb.train,/u/nlp/data/ner/column_data/conll.3class.train,/u/nlp/data/ner/column_data/wikiner.3class.train,/u/nlp/data/ner/column_data/ontonotes.3class.train,/u/nlp/data/ner/column_data/english.extra.3class.train, useNext=true, noMidNGrams=true, useTypeySequences=true, type=crf}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: maxAdditionalKnownLCWords
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.reinit(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:185)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.<init>(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:152)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.<init>(CRFClassifier.java:174)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.getClassifier(CRFClassifier.java:2967)
    at StanfordParserTest.main(StanfordParserTest.java:66)
```

Does anybody know what is going wrong here?

Comment: What version of the code are you using? My initial guess is that your code version and model version are mismatched.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm using version 3.6.0. I've downloaded the package on the following site: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml. And then used the "english all" model in the corresponding classifiers folder.

Answer (score 1):

Please consult the code given in NERDemo.java to see how to programmatically load a CRFClassifier.

These commands should run fine if run in the distribution directory:

```
javac -cp "*" NERDemo.java
java -mx400m -cp "*:.:lib/*" NERDemo classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz sample.txt
```

In general, make sure your CLASSPATH is only using the current jars from that distribution directory.  If you have outdated jars in your CLASSPATH you might get some errors.

This should work if you have the proper CLASSPATH:

```
String serializedClassifier = "classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";
AbstractSequenceClassifier<CoreLabel> classifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifier(serializedClassifier);
```

and are deserializing the models provided with the current distribution which are in the classifiers folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which jars do I have to add to the path? I have the following in the directory: stanford-ner-3.6.0-javadoc, stanford-ner-3.6.0-sources, stanford-ner-3.6.0 and stanford-ner. And the following are in the lib directory: joda-time, jollyday-0.4.7, slf4j-api, slf4j-simple, stanford-ner-resources. I have added all of them to the class path and got the maxAdditionalKnownLCWords exception. Are these non-compatible, e.g. do I only have to use either stanford-ner-3.6.0 or stanford-ner and not both?

Comment: Using all the jars in the distribution folder is fine.  If you download the distribution folder again and run the two commands above in that folder, NERDemo should work fine.  It works for me on my laptop.  Two reasons it might not work are you added jars to the folder or you overwrote the models files.  So a fresh download should fix that.  In your own code replicate what is in NERDemo.java.  You specifically want to use the getClassifier which takes in a String path to the model.